# JQuery Effect Multiple Elements

Tags: ajax, jquery

Trying to hit two elements with one `load()` and not successful in what I am trying.  This is what I have now to refresh a section on the page and it works fine.

```
$('#refreshme_'+request).load("http://www.example.com/add_list/");
```

I tried this

```
$('#refreshme_'+request, .xPlanner).load("http://www.example.com/add_list/");
```

and that did not work at all.  Want to make my code efficient and need to refresh 2 DOMs with one call.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = "foo";
$("#refreshme_" + request + ", .xPlanner").load("http://www.example.com/add_list/");
```

and

```
<div id="#refreshme_foo">Lorem</div>
<div class="xPlanner">Ipsum</div>
```

works. Was this what you where trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you can't use something like:

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/add_list/", function(data) {
    $('#refreshme_'+request).html(data);
    // same for second
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use .get instead:

```
    $.get("http://www.example.com/add_list/", function(data) {
        $("#refreshme1").html(data);
        $("#refreshme2").html(data);
    });
```

That's pseudo, but you get the idea.